# Google Play service for Location conflicts with Firebase dependencies

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available
at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.6.1.
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    }

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1'
    //map
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

When I am updating it to **9.6.1**, some of the classes are *not found*:

1. SupportMapFragment class
2. OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener, GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener listeners
3. LatLng, LatLngBounds, GoogleMap, Marker classes

Comment: for those classes, add this `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'`

Comment: When I am updating it to 9.6.1, some of the classes are not found:

SupportMapFragment class
OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener, GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener listeners
LatLng, LatLngBounds, GoogleMap, Marker classes

Comment: yes, just keep using version 9.6.1 for play-services-location and play-services-maps and the class will be there. You are missing the play-services-maps dependency

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the maps dependency to your gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
```

Comment: then i cant able to ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); method

Comment: Instead of getMap() use getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback(){ @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
         // Do what ever you want with the googleMap} });